# Find all buttons from a process ( API Functions )

Tags: c#, api, function

**1.** I have an application in which I'm trying to find all buttons from another form. I'm using the next 3 API functions:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

In my program, I check if the application that I want to check is running, and if true, I do the next:

```
    Process[] uWebCam = Process.GetProcessesByName("asd.vshost");
    if (uWebCam.Length != 0)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = uWebCam[0].MainWindowHandle;
        IntPtr x = FindWindowByIndex(ptr, 0);

        const int BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;
        SendMessage(x, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

And this is the function which I'm trying to find out the buttons by index (0, 1, ...):

```
static IntPtr FindWindowByIndex(IntPtr hWndParent, int index)
    {
        if (index == 0)
            return hWndParent;
        else
        {
            int ct = 0;
            IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;
            do
            {
                result = FindWindowEx(hWndParent, result, "Button", null);
                if (result != IntPtr.Zero)
                    ++ct;
            }
            while (ct < index && result != IntPtr.Zero);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

But the program doesn't press my first button of the another form ( index 0 button )

**2.** Is there any program that I can find all buttons name from a process that is running? I tried Spy++ but I didn't find anything useful...

Answer (score 1):

The `class` parameter to `FindWindowEx` is not the same thing as the class name in C#. It's the window class name, returned when you call [GetClassName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For example, the code below, run on my system (Windows 7 Enterprise, .NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2012) displays `"Classname is WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.b7ab7b_r13_ad1"`. Well, that's what it displayed the first time I ran it. The next time the returned value was different.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hwnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int nret;
    var className = new StringBuilder(255);
    nret = GetClassName(button1.Handle, className, className.Capacity);
    if (nret != 0)
        MessageBox.Show("Classname is " + className.ToString());
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Error getting window class name");
}
```

The window class name is apparently generated by the `Button` class static constructor, and changes with each execution of the program. So you can't use the full class name.

You *might* be able to look for the substring `".BUTTON."`, or possibly even `".BUTTON.app.0"`, as that appears to be constant. You might even be able to check that the string starts with `"WindowsForms"`, but I wouldn't advise adding the `"10"`, as I suspect that's the version number.

Whatever you do here, be advised that you're treading on undocumented implementation details of Windows Forms, which might change at any time.

Comment: Thank you Jim, but with the code and explanations given by you I can't resolve my problem ... The process that I'm trying to get it's buttons, it's not made in C# and I don't have its source code ... So all what I want is to access a button of this process...

Comment: @charqus: I would suggest that you write some code that calls `EnumChildWindows`, passing it the handle of the top-level window you're interested in. In the callback function, call `GetClassName` and output the returned value for each window. You might also send a `WM_GETTEXT` message to the window (don't try to use `GetWindowText` on a control that's in another process) to get the caption. All this should help you to identify the buttons. Then you can incorporate what you learn into the program you really want to write.

Comment: Actually this is the classname of the process that I'm trying to receive it's buttons: __ARCSOFT__MAGICAPP__WINDOW__CLASS__W__ ( I found this with AutoIT ) ; from here, is there posibility to access it's buttons? Here's a screenshot: http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/5641/grgb.png

Comment: You'll have to call `EnumChildWindows` on the top-level window and examine the class names of all the returned windows. That's the only way you'll be able to determine the buttons' class names.

Comment: I searched a lot to get a good EnumChildWindows, and to enumerate me all the Windows of my application, but I couldn't find a good-one. Can you please, help me with a workable function, or something like this? My process name is: uWebCam

Answer (score 0):

You should use `EnumChildWindows()` to find all child Windows.

**Api Functions:**

```
  public delegate bool EnumChildCallback(IntPtr hwnd, ref IntPtr lParam); 

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern int EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwnd, EnumChildCallback Proc, int lParam);

  [DllImport("User32.dll")]
  public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
```

**EnumChildWindows:**

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] uWebCam = Process.GetProcessesByName("asd.vshost");
            if (uWebCam .Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in uWebCam )
                {
                    IntPtr handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
                    EnumChildWindows(handle, EnumChildProc, 0);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Process can not be found!");
            }
```

**EnumChildProc:** Write your `SendMessage ()` function here

```
 public bool EnumChildProc(IntPtr hwndChild, ref IntPtr lParam)
    {
        SendMessage(hwndChild.ToInt32(), WM_SETTEXT, 0, textBox1.Text);
        return true;
    }
```

I hope this codes helps you.